# "The server was unable to save the form at this time. Please try again." Error while Creating or Editing List in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2016

When I create or edit list item, It says

> "The server was unable to save the form at this time. Please try again.".

I don't know what to do, any suggestion??
See below screenshot for error which I get.
[image: while creating]

[image: while editing]

[image: while viewing all items]

Answer (score 0):

**In case** of you got

> `“The server was unable to save the form at this time. Please try again.”` **for all users**.

Try to do the following:

- Restart `SharePoint Search Host Controller` service to free up some memory space.
- Make sure that the `Anonymous Authentication` was disabled in IIS.
- Set “minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService” attribute to **0** at `serviceHostingEnvironment` Tag in Web.Config.

  ```
   <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"  minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0"/>
  ```

**In case** of you got

> `“The server was unable to save the form at this time. Please try again.”` **for a specific user**.

If your list has `unique permissions` and a user/group has permissions only on that list and has `limited` or `no access` at the site level, then you run into this error.

For more details check [“The server was unable to save the form at this time. Please try again.”](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/10/02/the-server-was-unable-to-save-the-form-at-this-time-please-try-again-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Answer (score 0):

lease go to Site Settings page to check if the Limited-access user permission lockdown mode feature is activated in Site collection features page. If it is activated, please deactivate it.